# Failure INSTALL PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest, phonegap-build, android-logcat

I am getting a strange issue while installing application.

When I compiling my project there is no error but when I trying to launch its shows me,

Installation error: `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` Error.

I have tried so many thing related  Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error and also follow that rule but something goes wrong.

```
<manifest
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.0.1"
package="Work.Work"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="Work.Work" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" />

    <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler" />
    <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService" />
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="Work.Work.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="Work.Work.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />-->
<!--<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />-->
```

Comment: What is your `Package Name`  ? is it contains only `package="Work"` this ?

Comment: no,i will change package name.@jaydroider

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: i will check but this line have error      `<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**I was having this error because i had capital letters in my package name like this.**

```
Com.Droider.packagename;
```

After i had changed it to something like:

```
com.droider.packagename;
```

In your case try to change it to:

```
work.work;
```

**EDIT 1 :**

> May be this causes also.

```
android:name="MainActivity"
```

> Change this to.

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: i check all small latter like that com.droider.packagename;

Comment: Try your luck bhai. i don;'t be able to assume now. it's all the major issues this error have which i suggested. mostly it solve this.

Comment: Tell me 1 thing the package name in small letters replaced at all the places used in manifest. bcz i have noticed you have used it more than twice. so check that once bhai.

Comment: Changes at all the required place and checked right ? for small letters.

Comment: ok last but not list try with removing `support screens` part from manifest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111222/discussion-between-milan-patel-and-jaydroider).

Answer (score 11):

It May cause for Android 12 . For this

Add **`exported = true`** in your Activity
Example :

```
 <activity
            android:exported="true"   />
```

Comment: I had worked with another project with a more recent android studio (Electric Eel?), which gave proper errors for lack of `android:exported`, but then back to older Android Studio 4.1.3 for another older project updating to API level 33, it just fell to the generic manifest malformed message. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Just check all the

```
 android:name="..."
```

in your manifest and see if you forgot to put a dot in the beginning of a name that should have it, mostly names of your classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity
        android:exported="true"   />
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> package="Work"
> ```

APK manifest `package` names must contain at least one `.` separator in them. For example:

```
package="work.work"
```

You can read the [`PackageParser` source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java) to learn about various ways installation can fail with `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`.

Comment: it's not a solution ,i change package name.

Comment: It's one problem you have. There may be others.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i put ':' on value of android:process

```
<service
        android:name=".Views.Views.services.MyService"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. **I had create a new package Start with capital letter. Its leads to this same problem .**  Check your **all package folder names and be sure all in small letters**.

[image: it was my problem]

*Happy coding*

Answer (score 0):

in my case 
if you have changed your activity to fragment
then remove that activity name from your androidmanifest.xml file

```
<activity
        android:name=".fragment_change_password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

remove this type of lines from manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Your package name has a capital letter in it. Try refactoring your package so that all the letters are lowercase. To do this, in the panel for your project, make sure you're in Android view mode, then click the gear that is a little to the right of the view indicator, then make sure compact empty middle packages is unchecked. Next, right click on your package with a capital letter in it and select refactor -> rename. Change it to have a lower case, double check your AndroidManifest.xml is now a lower case, if not, manually edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file meta data tag will be available for each xml resource file .
If that meta data doesn't have android:resource location , this issue will arise .

Example :

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.actions"
   android:resource="@drawable/cellphone"/>
```

Comment: Please complete your answer as this seems to be missing some part.

Answer (score 0):

in my case place i placed **Application** class outside side main package folder.

just move Application class to root activities folder.

Answer (score 0):

the exported flag should be present to activities which has intent filter, receivers, services, providers...

in my case i missed receiver and provider

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```