# I get an error when I try to run the emulator. Is it a problem with the version?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I want to solve the error that occurs when I try to run the emulator.

About a week ago, I was using `Firestore` and got the following error.

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

Therefore, I tried another version of the emulator, which was 28, as shown below.

[image]

However, although the above error was resolved, another error appeared. Here it is.

The problem or error message you are experiencing:

[image]

I think I tried everything I could find by googling error messages.
For example, I wiped the emulator data, checked and changed the version, and so on.

#### Summary of questions

First of all, I would like to understand and solve the error message in the picture.
If anyone knows the solution, please let me know.
Also, is it safe to use API31 for the emulator?

Comment: Also you can check [Failure INSTALL PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37066617/10157127)

Comment: Posting your android manifest may help us to help you, as it seems to be a problem with it